# How calculate progress

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a gui in which I need to show the user a progress bar on how much a file has downloaded from the internet. I succeeded in using tqdm and display it to the console. But I'm having a problem in passing that to the gui.

The problem I'm facing is updating the progress bar with the percentage value of the tqdm. Since tqdm wraps its progress bar, I'm unable to get the percentage as an integer or float. I tried `bar_format='{percentage:.0f}`. This does give me the percentage only, but that's about it. It still doesn't return the percentage itself as an integer or float.

This is the loop in which the progress bar gets displayed and the file is downloaded:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import path
import sys
from tqdm import tqdm

folderPath = 'C:/Users/Sammy/Desktop/'

url = 'http://www.karavalimunjavu.com/'
res = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

# Downloading images.
for images in soup.select('img[data-big]'):
    imgDownload = get(url+images.get('data-big'), stream=True)
    file_size = int(imgDownload.headers.get("Content-Length", None))
    progress = tqdm(total=file_size, file=sys.stdout, bar_format='{percentage:.0f}')
    with open(path.join(folderPath, pageNo), 'wb') as f:
        for data in imgDownload:
            f.write(data)
            progress.update(len(data))
        f.close()
        progress.close()
    break
```

How do I get it to work in a way that it outputs the percentage as an integer?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: My bad. Provided.

Comment: How should this have anything to do with tqdm? You have the total `file_size`, the downloaded data is progressively updated using `len(data)`. Can't you do the math?

Comment: Where is the gui code?

Comment: @musicamante Oh yeah, just figured that out. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is pretty straightforward if I had looked a little more carefully.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import path

folderPath = 'C:/Users/Sammy/Desktop/'

url = 'http://www.karavalimunjavu.com/'
res = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

for images in soup.select('img[data-big]'):
    pageNo = path.basename(images.get('data-big'))[15:]
    imgDownload = get(url+images.get('data-big'), stream=True)
    file_size = int(imgDownload.headers.get("Content-Length", None))
    progress = 0  # Initialise progress variable
    with open(path.join(folderPath, pageNo), 'wb') as f:
        for data in imgDownload:
            f.write(data)
            progress += len(data)
            print((progress/file_size)*100)  # The logic to print out the percentage
        f.close()
    break
```